# Pandas df.shift(axis=1) adds extra entries, why?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, shift

Here is a sample of the original table.

```
    #     z  speed   dir  U_geo  V_geo   U  U[QCC]  U[ign]  U[siC]  U[siD]   V
0  40  2.83  181.0  0.05   2.83  -0.20  11   -0.20    2.24    0.95    2.83  11
1  50  2.41  184.8  0.20   2.40  -0.01  11   -0.01    2.47    0.94    2.41  11
2  60  1.92  192.4  0.41   1.88   0.25  11    0.25    2.46    0.94    1.91  11
3  70  1.75  201.7  0.65   1.63   0.50  11    0.50    2.47    0.94    1.68  11
```

I need to shift the entire table over by 1 column to produce this:

```
    z  speed   dir  U_geo  V_geo   U  U[QCC]  U[ign]  U[siC]  U[siD]   V
0  40  2.83  181.0  0.05   2.83  -0.20  11   -0.20    2.24    0.95    2.83  
1  50  2.41  184.8  0.20   2.40  -0.01  11   -0.01    2.47    0.94    2.41  
2  60  1.92  192.4  0.41   1.88   0.25  11    0.25    2.46    0.94    1.91  
3  70  1.75  201.7  0.65   1.63   0.50  11    0.50    2.47    0.94    1.68
```

Here is the code that ingests the data and tries to shift it over by one column

```
wind_rass_table_df=pd.read_csv(file_path, header=j+3, engine='python', nrows=77,sep=r'\s{2,}',skip_blank_lines=False,index_col=False)
wind_rass_table_df=wind_rass_table_df.shift(periods=1,axis=1)
```

Supposedly df.shift(axis=1) should shift the dataframe over by 1 column but it does more than that, it does this:

```
    #   z  speed    dir  U_geo  V_geo     U  U[QCC]  U[ign]  U[siC]
0 NaN NaN   2.83  181.0   0.05   2.83  40.0   -0.20   -0.20    2.24
1 NaN NaN   2.41  184.8   0.20   2.40  50.0   -0.01   -0.01    2.47
2 NaN NaN   1.92  192.4   0.41   1.88  60.0    0.25    0.25    2.46
3 NaN NaN   1.75  201.7   0.65   1.63  70.0    0.50    0.50    2.47
```

The shift function has taken the first column, inserted into the 7th column, shifted the 7th into the 8th and repeated the 8th, shifting the 9th over and so on.

What is the correct way of shifting a dataframe over by one column?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use iloc and create another dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.iloc[:, :-1], columns=df.columns[1:], index=df.index)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It does seem like a brute force method, though.  One would think that the shift function would do the trick.

Comment: It is not a brute force method since it basically just use pandas slicing, I don't think you will find a faster method even with shift because when using it you have to insert the NaN values in the data frame which consumes time